# MySQL: null check based on if statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, null-check

I have this procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE add_package(nam VARCHAR(255), pack_id INT, lib_id INT, descrip TEXT)
  BEGIN
  DECLARE ind INT;
  DECLARE `_rollback` BOOL DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET `_rollback` = 1;
    START TRANSACTION;
      INSERT INTO java_master (name, description) VALUES (nam, descrip);

      SET ind = (SELECT id FROM java_master WHERE name = nam AND description = descrip);

      INSERT INTO java_package (master_id, parent_package_id, library_id) VALUES (ind, pack_id, lib_id);
      IF `_rollback` THEN
        ROLLBACK;
      ELSE
        COMMIT;
    END IF;
  END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I need to make that set statement in the middle get both return the `id` in the `java_master` table even if description is a null value... any suggestions as to how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not supplying a value for the "id" column, I'm going to assume your id is an auto incrementing value.

-- What I imagine your table looks like? SHOW CREATE TABLE java_master;

```
CREATE TABLE java_master (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name CHAR(10), description VARCHAR(200));
```

-- Example inserting null

```
INSERT INTO java_master(name, description)
VALUES("class", NULL);
```

-- If this is the case, you should be using LAST_INSERT_ID() to get the last created auto incrementing value for the table. SET ind to this.

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

If you insist on doing it how you have it, then I supposed you could do this:

```
SELECT id FROM java_master WHERE name = nam AND IFNULL(description, "") = IFNULL(descrip, "");
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: I do not at all insist on doing it my way... LAST_INSERT_ID() is SOOO much easier and more fool_proof! thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer provided by Voidmain, the solution to my problem is made irrelevant with the following code...

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE add_package(nam VARCHAR(255), pack_id INT, lib_id INT, descrip TEXT)
  BEGIN
  DECLARE `_rollback` BOOL DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET `_rollback` = 1;
    START TRANSACTION;
      INSERT INTO java_master (name, description) VALUES (nam, descrip);
      INSERT INTO java_package (master_id, parent_package_id, library_id) VALUES ((SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()), pack_id, lib_id);
      IF `_rollback` THEN
        ROLLBACK;
      ELSE
        COMMIT;
    END IF;
  END //
DELIMITER ;
```